# Cannot display the proper value using Django and Python

Tags: python, xml, django

I could not fetch and display the value using Django and Python. My code is below:

```
    def viewbook(request):
        doc = minidom.parse("roomlist.xml")
        staffs = doc.getElementsByTagName("location")
        root = []
        for staff in staffs:
            lname=staff.getAttribute("name");
            roomname=staff.getElementsByTagName("roomname")[0]
            seat=staff.getElementsByTagName("noseats")[0]
            project=staff.getElementsByTagName("projectorscreen")[0]
            video=staff.getElementsByTagName("videoconf")[0]
            root.append({'lname':lname,'roomname':roomname,'seat':seat,'project':project,'video':video})
return render(request,'booking/viewbook.html',{'people': root})
```

Here I am fetching the data from my `.xml` sheet and the sheet is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><roomlist>
  <location name="Bangalore">
    <room id="1uy92j908u092">
      <roomname> Aquarius </roomname>
      <noseats> 10 </noseats>
      <projectorscreen>yes</projectorscreen>
      <videoconf>yes</videoconf>
    </room>
  </location>
<location name="Bhubaneswar"><room id="131198912460"><roomname>cottage</roomname><noseats>5</noseats><projectorscreen>Yes</projectorscreen><videoconf>Yes</videoconf></room></location></roomlist>
```

Here I am trying to display the values in tabular format and the code is given below.

```
<tr>
            <th>Location Name</th>
            <th>Room Name</th>
            <th>seats</th>
            <th>Projector screen</th>
            <th>Video Conference</th>
        </tr>
    {% for person in people %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{person.lname}}</td>
            <td>{{person.roomname}}</td>
            <td>{{person.seat}}</td>
            <td>{{person.project}}</td>
            <td>{{person.video}}</td>
        </tr>
```

But in my case I am getting the below kind of output.

```
Location Name       Room Name    seats   Projector screen    Video Conference
Bangalore   <DOM Element: roomname at 0x7fcc35275440>   <DOM Element: noseats at 0x7fcc35275560>    <DOM Element: projectorscreen at 0x7fcc35275290>    <DOM Element: videoconf at 0x7fcc352757a0>
Bhubaneswar <DOM Element: roomname at 0x7fcc35262cf8>   <DOM Element: noseats at 0x7fcc374fb6c8>    <DOM Element: projectorscreen at 0x7fcc36579128>    <DOM Element: videoconf at 0x7fcc352756c8>
```

Here I need to get all proper value from the XML sheet.

Comment: where is your return statement ?

Comment: Look at minidom's API docs on how to extract attribute values like `'name'` and the value in the node.

Comment: Can you modify it ?

Comment: @Arun : Please check the updated post.

Answer (score 2):

you have to get the element value by `firstChild.nodeValue` or `firstChild.data` of the xml, try this:

```
def viewbook(request):
    doc = minidom.parse("roomlist.xml")
    staffs = doc.getElementsByTagName("location")
    root = []
    for staff in staffs:
        lname=staff.getAttribute("name");
        roomname=staff.getElementsByTagName("roomname")[0].firstChild.nodeValue.strip()
        seat=staff.getElementsByTagName("noseats")[0].firstChild.nodeValue.strip()
        project=staff.getElementsByTagName("projectorscreen")[0].firstChild.nodeValue.strip()
        video=staff.getElementsByTagName("videoconf")[0].firstChild.nodeValue.strip()
```

Comment: @satya Cool, glad it works, better `strip()` it after get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what's an example from the docs, `node.data` is the way you get data from a node that only contains text.

```
def getText(nodelist): 
  rc = [] for node in nodelist: 
  if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:      
    rc.append(node.data)
  return "".join(rc)
```

[docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can get

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
doc = parse("dd.xml")
staffs = doc.getElementsByTagName("location")
root = []
for staff in staffs:
    lname=staff.getAttribute("name");
    roomname=staff.getElementsByTagName("roomname")[0].firstChild.wholeText
    seat=staff.getElementsByTagName("noseats")[0].firstChild.wholeText
    project=staff.getElementsByTagName("projectorscreen")[0].firstChild.wholeText
    video=staff.getElementsByTagName("videoconf")[0].firstChild.wholeText
    root.append({'lname':lname,'roomname':roomname,'seat':seat,'project':project,'video':video})
print root
```

output

```
[{'lname': u'Bangalore', 'roomname': u' Aquarius ', 'video': u'yes', 'project': u'yes', 'seat': u' 10 '}, {'lname': u'Bhubaneswar', 'roomname': u'cottage', 'video': u'Yes', 'project': u'Yes', 'seat': u'5'}]
```